# Is there a way to validate the broker's SSL certificate in django-celery?

Tags: ssl-certificate, celery, django-celery

I'm using django-celery do connect to a RabbitMQ broker through SSL (with the BROKER_USE_SSL setting). Is there a way to:

1. Verify the certificate of the broker when the connection is established.
2. Configure a client certificate to us to establish the connection.

The RabbitMQ side is working correctly, but I don't know how to configure Celery for this and I haven't found anything in Celery's documentation either. The settings CELERY_SECURITY_KEY, CELERY_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE and CELERY_SECURITY_CERT_STORE look like they could do this, but it seems that they're only used for message signing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kombu.Connection accepts ssl argument as a dictionary of SSL configuration (ssl=False by default). I suppose it is applicable for BROKER_USE_SSL too.

```
BROKER_USE_SSL={
    'ca_certs': '/etc/pki/tls/certs/something.crt',
    'keyfile': '/etc/something/system.key',
    'certfile': '/etc/something/system.cert',
    'cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
}
```